# Equivalence between two definitions of bounded functions

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I was studying from Lindstrom (Spaces: Introduction to Real Analysis) and I have troubles with a problem of section 4.5.

It said the following:

> Show that the two ways of defining a bounded function are equivalent
> (one says that the set of values $\{f(x) : x ∈ X\}$ is a bounded set;
> the other one says that for any $a ∈ X$, there is a constant $M_a$
> such that $d_Y (f(a), f(x)) ≤ M_a$ for all $x ∈ X$).

I've started using this definition:

> a function $f : X → Y$ is bounded if the set of values $\{f(x) : x ∈ X\}$ is a bounded set, i.e., if there is a constant $K ∈ R$
> such that $d_Y (f(u), f(v)) ≤ K$ for all $u, v ∈ X.$

And I think than I could use a fixed point, called $a \in X$, to prove this equivalence:

**My Attempt**

1. a function $f : X → Y$ is bounded if the set of values $\{f(x) : x ∈ X\}$ is a bounded set, i.e., if there is a constant $K ∈ R$
   such that $d_Y (f(u), f(v)) ≤ K$ for all $u, v ∈ X.$
2. $a ∈ X$, there is a constant $M_a$  such that $d_Y (f(a), f(x)) ≤ M_a$ for all $x ∈ X$).

(2) $\to$ (1) :

> $\exists K \geq 0$ such that $d_Y (f(x), f(y)) \leq K$ for all $x,y \in X$.
>
> Let $x=a$, then $\forall y$, we have $d_Y (f(a), f(y)) \leq K$.
>
> $\therefore$ $K = M_a$ $\forall a \in X$

(1) $\to $ (2):

> Let $a \in X$,  $\exists M_a$ such that $d_Y(f(x), f(a)) \leq M_a $
> $\forall x,y \in X $
>
> So, let $a$ a fixed point and
>
> $d_Y (f(x), f(y)) \leq d_Y (f(x), f(a)) + d_Y (f(a), f(y)) \leq 2M_a$, because $d_Y(f(x), f(a)) \leq M_a $.
>
> We define $K=2M_a$, and we have
>
> $d_Y (f(x), f(y)) \leq K$ for $K \geq 0 $

It's correct?

Comment: Step Zero is: do you fully understand the problem? Are you comfortable with "metric space" notion? "bounded set" notion? (Can you write the definition?) Do you agree that $f:X \to Y$ is a function into a metric space?

Comment: @311411 I recently started with this chapter and I'm not fully convinced with the form of how the text show this content :( It's a little confusing to me when I read this section in particular, and it hasn't examples

Comment: Of course you are allowed to look at different books, articles, sites etc. I myself do not know Lindstrom. The outline is a two step process. First step is assume definition A, and use it to prove definition B must be true. Then reverse roles. (perhaps it may help to fix a specific example. Say $f(x)=\arctan(x).$ This is surely a bounded function.)

Comment: @311411 A function $f : X \to Y$ is bounded if the set of functions $\{ f(x) : x \in X \}$ is bounded. I could write this using a constant K, such that $d_Y ((f(u), f(v)) \leq K $ for all $u,v \in X $. Using this part of the definition I could prove it

Comment: (+1) That is good. (although I would say "the set of function *values*".) Maybe you should edit your post above with your attempt of this direction of the proof.